# Apollo GraphQL client query returns introspection result instead of data

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I'm currently trying to get data from the *Squidex* API for a *NextJS* app, by using *Apollo* as *GraphQL* client.
On `localhost`, both in `dev/production` mode, everything works fine.

After deploying the app on *Heroku*, the same query returns the introspection schema as result, instead of the expected data. On a real example, by running a query like:

```
{
    queryPageContents(search: "Home") {
      ...PagesFragmentsPageId
      data {
        ...PagesFragmentsPage
        ...PagesFragmentsHome
      }
    }
  }

  ${Pages.fragments.pageId}
  ${Pages.fragments.page}
  ${Pages.fragments.home}
}
```

Basically I'm asking various data about a webpage, using fragments and so on.
My expected data should be as follows - such as on `localhost`:

[image]

But I'm receiving this on Heroku instead of the above one:

[image]

Because of this, my app fails its rendering because my code looks for a JSON node called `queryPageContents` - as shown in the first screenshot - but It's currently receiving `__schema` as query result. So this causes a `500` error on front-end.

I googled around and I've found this [graphql-disable-introspection](https://github.com/helfer/graphql-disable-introspection) that has to be installed on server-side. I don't know if it could solve this issue, but I'm not getting how this could happens.

Any advice about this?

Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sebastian Stehle from Squidex noticed, by deferring the page data initialization after a data loading check, the issue it beings solved. In a NextJS scenario like this:

```
[...]
  const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(PAGE_QUERY.pages.home);
  // Instead here, pages it's being moved after error/loading checking as follows

  // Exception check
  if (error) {
    return <ErrorDb error={error} />
  }
  // DB fetching check
  if (loading) {
    return null;
  }

  // Data initialization here
  const pages = data.queryPageContents;

  return (
   // Page
   [...]
  );
[...]
```